# Replace a an expression in Exponential only but not in other terms?

Tags: replacement

I want to replace the A in the Exponent only but when I use the replace  rule it also replaces the Derivative of A.

```
Exp[A + 2 B] (3 Derivative[1][A] + 4 Derivative[2][A]) /. A -> A + 6 Subscript[f, 3]
```

which gives me the output

```
Times[Power[E,Plus[A,Times[2,B],Times[6,Subscript[f,3]]]],Plus[Times[3,Derivative[1][Plus[A,Times[6,Subscript[f,3]]]]],Times[4,Derivative[2][Plus[A,Times[6,Subscript[f,3]]]]]]]
```

I want the output to show like this

```
Exp[A + 6 Subscript[f, 3] + 2B] (3 Derivative[1][A] + 4 Derivative[2][A])
```

Any idea?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I typically do that like this: `Exp[A + 2 B] (3 Derivative[1][A] + 4 Derivative[2][A]) /. 
 Exp[a_] :> Exp[a /. A -> A + 6 Subscript[f, 3]]`. Sort of nested replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the derivatives by prepending another rule to the one you already use. I.e. use:

```
rules = {e : Derivative[_][A] -> e, A -> A + 6 Subscript[f, 3]}
yourExpression /. rules
```

Answer (score 1):

Try being more explicit

```
Exp[A + 2 B] (3 Derivative[1][A] + 4 Derivative[2][A]) /. 
 Exp[A + 2 B] -> Exp[A + 6 Subscript[f, 3] + B]
```

> E^(A + B + 
>     6 Subscript[f, 3]) (3 Derivative[1][A] + 4 A^[Prime][Prime])

Does that help?

On a seperate point I would recommend against using `Subscript`. You can simply use `f[3]` and this works well if you need to have a symbolic value in the subscript i.e. `f[n]`

I hope you enjoy Mathematica.